# Can a scanner read input of different types

Tags: java, type-conversion, java.util.scanner

I'm rather new to java and I am playing around with scanners. This is my code:

```
    System.out.print("Name? ");
    String name = s.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Height? ");
    double height = s.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Haircolor? ");
    String haircolor = s.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Age? ");
    int age = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Job? ");
    String job = s.nextLine();
```

As you can probably see, I'm getting input about some person. Now the problem is that it gives an `InoutMismatchException` when I try to read the double. After reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-value-string-to-double) I changed that line to `double height = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine());`. That works but now it doesn't stop after printing "Job? ". The program just goes on without reading anything.

Can anyone maybe tell me why that is? And also why I got this exception? I just suspected that a scanner maybe can't read different types (double, string, int) and can't *"switch back"* to `String` after having read an `int`. But that seems kinda odd.

Thank you so much in advance for an answer.

Tony

Comment: I guess this class is reading about the scanner line by line.

Comment: Add another `nextLine` after `nextDouble` and after `nextInt`.

Comment: Every other Javaquestion is about Scanner (the others about NullPointerException with unitialized array elements, string comparisions and ArrayOutOfBoundExceptions). What is it with this class that makes it so difficult? Is the API documentation somehow misguiding? (Just want to understand.)

Comment: For me from the documentation it's not really clear how the individual methods (nextDouble, nextLine and so on) deal with \n. And when they are called. So e.g. is looks nextDouble() for a double once i hit return in the console? 
And I think a scanner is kinda one of the first things one learns when learning java. So it's lots of beginners.

Because you just wanted to understand ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
        System.out.print("Name? ");
        String name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Height? ");
        double height = s.nextDouble();
        s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Haircolor? ");
        String haircolor = s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Age? ");
        int age = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Job? ");
        String job = s.nextLine();
```

Comment: it also gives me the exception after input the height and hit enter. (I just copied your code).

Comment: The InputMismatchException

Comment: i don't get any exception for following input. **Name? subash
Height? 184
Haircolor? black
Age? 22
Job? student**