# how to extract double from a string like this

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

How to extract double values from a string?

For example, `s= "1.2+3.4*(3.2+2.3)-12.1/3.4*1.8+5.7"`

How do extract the double values, and store it as variables?

Comment: do pattern matching and grab the matching portion

Comment: How do I do pattern matching?Thanks!

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number), it has been answered already.

Comment: first convert it into char array, then search for all the operations, +,-,* and /. You can push them into stack and then take the chars till next operator.

Comment: Have you tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/java-convert-string-to-double)? I think it's what you need

Comment: I would suggest searching for regular expression examples in the code base you use, I think your getting a "pass" for being female. normally such a question which is not researched would get you boiled in oil.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Pattern matching and grab matching portion out

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("1.2+3.4*(3.2+2.3)-12.1/3.4*1.8+5.7");

while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

You can then collect all matched data to a `List<Double>` or `List<Float>` based on your requirement

To collect operators as well you need to add another pattern to look for as well see the ORing section

```
([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)|(\+|-|\/|\(|\|\)|\*)
```

---

**See**

- [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/e4aRlP)

Comment: what kind of head do I need to import for Pattern and Matcher?

Comment: `java.util.regex.Pattern` & `java.util.regex.Matcher`

Comment: The Netbeans shows red line under the Pattern and Matcher, and it says cannot find class Pattern and Matcher, so my question is if I need to import something?

Comment: As mentioned you need to import these two classes

Comment: My last question is how do I store each characters as a varible.  I mean numbers and +,-,/ all those signs in a varible?

Comment: You can store each matched data into a List as mentioned in answer, if you want to grab operators (`-`, `+`, etc..) you will have to change the pattern so that it grabs them as well

Comment: how do I grab the +-/*, could you show me the code?

Comment: how do I  do the pattern match for"+,-,*,/"?