# Excel to java and calculate the values

Tags: java, eclipse, excel

I need to make an if loop that if the column in excel says ''cov'' it should take the values in the 14th column and calculate them together.
The thing is, I know when I take the values they will come as a string and I need to parse them in to a double, how can I do that?

```
if(workbook.getSheet(0).getCell(0, rowno+1).getContents().equals("cov")){
    for(int i=1; i<=8; i++){
        String excel = workbook.getSheet(0).getCell(13, rowno+1).getContents();
        System.out.println(excel);
        rowno++;
    }
}
```

It will print out the right values, but I cannot convert them nor calculate them together.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here:

[Convert String to double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java)

```
String excel = "99.99"; // example String
double value = Double.parseDouble(excel);
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse string as double use below line:-

```
Double.parseDouble(excel)
```

And to sum up all in your loop instantiate one double variable "Double sum=0.0" outside the loop and initialize it with 0.0 and in your loop you can do sum+=  Double.parseDouble(excel);