# String + Double in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, string, double

My problem is this:

```
Double result = SubActivity.this.resultado(SubActivity.this.num1, SubActivity.this.pes1, SubActivity.this.num2, SubActivity.this.pes2, 
    SubActivity.this.num3, SubActivity.this.pes3, 
    SubActivity.this.num4, SubActivity.this.pes4, 
    SubActivity.this.num5, SubActivity.this.pes5);                  

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubActivity.this);                    
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);                    
builder.setTitle(R.string.result);                    
builder.setMessage(R.string.n + result);                    
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);                    
builder.show();                 
return;
```

But I got a error:

> There is no applicable method to '(double)'

How i can add the string?

Comment: if your intent is to concatenate R.string.n to result, you can use getString(R.string.n) + result

Comment: Worked :D thanks Blackbelt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that there is an implicit cast from string to double because your function returns a string, but you are storing in it a result of type double.

Your code:

```
Double result = String functionThatReturnsAString();
```

You need to use the Double.parseDouble() function for the conversion

```
Double result = Double.parseDouble(functionThanReturnsAString());
```

Comment: I grab the double in the EditText, the "Double result" are only numbers.

Comment: What I mean is that EditText returns a string and there is no implicit cast (Double)string, so you have to use the parseDouble function for the conversion. I believe the other answers are better though because it looks like you only need the string, you are only storing the Double to convert it back to a string later.

Comment: I got with other method Tony Ruth, anyway thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
builder.setMessage(Double.parseDouble(getResources.getString(R.String.n))+ result)+"");
```

(You may need to tinker a bit to get the string from `R.string.n`

[the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5769679/609782)

Comment: Error:  -Unknown entity 'getResources'

Comment: use context or whatever that makes you use `getResources()`. (I guess you might have figured it out). Or if not, its a small google query away!