# How do i split user input in java - and convert into double?

Tags: java, string, split, converters

I'm making a currency converter i Java. 
The user types in both amount and currency ( 10 USD).

I first need to split the user input into two strings, 
and then convert one of them to a double variable, need some help With this..

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of value (double) and currency name. (eg. 10 USD)");
String streng = tastatur.nextLine();

//Split ??
String wordsplit = streng.split(" ", 2);
```

So i need the first part of the user input to be converted to double, so i can calculate currency etc.

Comment: dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java

Comment: Currency should never be dealt with double. Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> i need the first part of the user input to be converted to double,

All numeric data types have a parse method to convert the String value to a numeric value:

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble( wordsplit[0] );
```

It will throw an example is the String is not a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built in Double class to parse the double, so you would have:

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of value (double) and currency name. (eg. 10 USD)");
String streng = tastatur.nextLine();

//splits the string
String wordsplit = streng.split(" ");
double d = Double.parseDouble(wordsplit[0]);
```

EDIT:
If you wish for a number such as 19.00 USD to show you will need to do a bit of coding wizardry, because if a double ends with a zero(other than the first e.g 19.0) then it gets truncated, so if you convert it to a string you will be left with 19.0 instead of 19.00

Answer (score 0):

You can either write a parser OR use `java.lang.text.NumberFormat`:

```
package money;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * ParseDemo
 * @author Michael
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585135/how-do-i-split-user-input-in-java-and-convert-into-double
 * @since 11/7/2015 11:45 AM
 */
public class ParseDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "10.01 USD";

        System.out.println(String.format("amount: %10.2f", parseMoney(test)));

        test = "$10.04";
        try {
            double amount = (NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)).parse(test).doubleValue();
            System.out.println(String.format("amount: %10.2f", amount));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static double parseMoney(String usd) {
        double amount = -1.0;
        if ((usd != null) && (usd.trim().length() > 0)) {
            usd = usd.replace("$", "");
            String [] tokens = usd.split("\\s+");
            if (tokens.length > 0) {
                amount = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
            }
        }
        return amount;
    }
}
```