# Error: bad operand types for binary operator '*' first type: java.lang.String second type: double

Tags: java

I'm using the `JOptionPane` Class.

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Annual income?");   
String income;         
income = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Annual income?");    

double tax = income-income*0.3;                                             
double salary = (tax/12);                             

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,"Monthly in-hand salary is $"+monthly);   
System.exit(0);
```

It says there's an error on the "double tax" line but I don't know what's wrong. It also mentions a `java.lang.String error` but I don't know what that means either. How can I fix this?

Comment: It means you can't multiply a string.

Comment: The error is clear. A string cannot be one of the operands for an arithmentic operation. You are multiplying a string and a double, and this is not possible. You need to [convert it to double first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java).

Comment: Convert the string to double?

Comment: @madcity Yes. A string is not a number, it can't be used as operand for a multiplication. You need to convert it to a number first. See the link in my previous comment

Comment: If you prefer not to let your question stand on Stack Overflow as the question it was (which is all fine and understandable), you may delete it completely. Please do this rather than leaving a “question” that future readers won’t make sense of anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not remove the original question once it has been answered. This may help other users in the future. Have made a request to roll back to revision 4.

Answer (score -1):

The error should be interpreted as:

"***you can not get a Double as the result of multiplying a STRING by a number...***"

you need to **PARSE** the String first then you can do math with that value...

the solution

use the static method  `Double.parseDouble()`

```
double dIncome =    Double.parseDouble(income);
double tax = dIncome -dIncome *0.3;
```

Answer (score -1):

the error appears here `double tax = income-income*0.3;`. This is due to the fact that you're attempting to multiply a string with a number which is impossible.

to solve the issue try this:

```
double income = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Annual income?")); // you can expand on this by validating prior to assigning
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse the String to a double somehow first. You can't simply multiply a number with a String and expect that to work. `Double.parseDouble(String s)` is a good choice.

Try:

```
double income =
    Double.parseDouble(
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Annual income?"));
```

instead.

[Javadoc for Double.parseDouble() (Java Platform SE 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))