# How to convert the string arraylist into the double so that the arraylist could return sorted value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a list of Airlines deals which has Fare in the form of

> C$145.19,C$298.17,CC$398.17,C$876.21,C$1001.71

and the deal is shown on the basis of fare sorted from lower to higher.

I have to create a script which pulls this fare and check whether the deals is appearing on the basis of fare from lower to higher. But I am using the array list as string instead of double.

How to convert the string arraylist into the double so that the arraylist could return sorted value?

Code:

```
ArrayList<String> dealList = new ArrayList<>();

List<Webelement> deals = driver.findelements(By.xpath//"div[@class='xyz']");
// It pulls out all the Fare with same Xpath which is almost 10 value.

for(Webelement w: deals)
{
deallist.add(w.gettext());
}

ArrayList<String> newDeaList = new ArrayList<>();

for(String s: dealList)
{
newDealList.add(s);
}

Collections.sort(newDealList);
Assert.Assertequals(dealList,newDealList);
```

But I am not getting the correct output .

Output Value:

> C$145.19,C$298.17,CC$398.17,C$876.21,C$1001.71

Comment: you don't need to turn it into a number, and as long as that C$ are in the values, you can't either

Comment: Side note: you want to provide a **real** [mcve] here. The code you are showing doesn't give hints what is going on.

Comment: See on a webpage we have list of airline deals are showing from certain origin to destination with certain fares. The deals are already sorted on the basis of fare. I have to create a script for it so that the deals are sorted. My approach. I have taken webelement of type list and pulled the xpath of it. Then i have added the list into array list and pulled the value by gettext. Now in another list i have copied the same value and applied collection.sort to sort it and then comparing both list which should return true as the first list already return sorted value

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something like:

```
Collections.sort(stringArray, (s1, s2) -> {
    return Double.valueOf(s1.split('$')[1])
        .compareTo(Double.valueOf(s2.split('$')[1]));
});
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
Collections.sort(stringArray.stream().map(s -> Double.valueOf(s.split('$')[1])));
```

All this having been said, you seem to be comparing equality of two *different* arrays at the end of your code-snippet, an operation that will always return false as they will be comparing address equality.

EDIT: (After clarification on the problem - here is how to compare two arrays for equality)

```
boolean compareArrays(List<String> arr1, List<String> arr2) {
    if (arr1.size() != arr2.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++) {
        if (!arr1.get(i).equals(arr2.get(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I should not change the above code. Only instead of Collection & Assert True i should integrate this code

Comment: Am I to understand that your problem is checking equality between the two arrays? Or in sorting?

Comment: Nice answer for a newbie, worth an upvote! And just in case you intend to practice the newly gained upvote privilege ... I am glad to help ;-)

Comment: See on a webpage we have list of airline deals are showing from certain origin to destination with certain fares. The deals are already sorted on the basis of fare. I have to create a script for it so that the deals are sorted. My approach. I have taken webelement of type list and pulled the xpath of it. Then i have added the list into array list and pulled the value by gettext. Now in another list i have copied the same value and applied collection.sort to sort it and then comparing both list which should return true as the first list already return sorted value from webpage

Answer (score 1):

Converting string values into double is fully outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java) for example. In your case, you want to look into using [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) - you specify a pattern that can be used to extract the "numberic" parts of those strings.

Beyond that, it is clear that a comparison of a **sorted** list of strings and an **unsorted** version of that list should result in `false` - as most likely, both lists have the same elements, but in different order! In any case: you could still go in and simply iterate **both** lists manually and compare each entry to identify the one causing the mismatch; to then have a closer look.

Finally: and keep in mind that using double/Double to represent **currency** is possible, but a no-go in "real world" applications. Floating point numbers come with rounding errors; thus you should rather look into using [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: Already the deals are in sorted order on the basis of fare on the webpage. Please check the screenshot

Comment: Which screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean ValidateSortedList() {
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> pageList = new ArrayList<>();

    Collections.addAll(stringList, "C$145.19", "C$298.17", "C$398.17");
    System.out.println("deal list in selenium: " + stringList);

    for (String fareInString : stringList) {
        int indexOfFare = findIndex(fareInString);

        Double fareInDouble = Double.parseDouble(fareInString.substring(indexOfFare));
        pageList.add(fareInDouble);
    }

    List<Double> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(pageList);

    Collections.sort(sortedList);
    System.out.println("web page :" + pageList);
    System.out.println("selenuim test list :" + sortedList);
    boolean equals = sortedList.equals(pageList);

    System.out.println("is list equal :"
            + sortedList.equals(pageList));
    return equals;

}

private int findIndex(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your code.