# String cannot be converted to double

Tags: java, string, double, calculator, value-of

I am trying to make a calculator with Java, and everything worked normally until this error popped up:
imcompatible types:

String cannot be converted to double

Invalid value type 'String' for format specifier '%.0f', parameter 1

This is the script:

```
private void btnResultActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    String answer;

    second = Double.parseDouble(display.getText()); // The second number to count
    if (operation == "+") {
        answer = String.valueOf(first + second);
        result = String.format("%.0f",answer);
        display.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    } else if (operation == "-") {
        answer = String.valueOf(first - second);
        result = String.format("%.0f",answer);
        display.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    } else if (operation == "*") {
        answer = String.valueOf(first * second);
        result = String.format("%.0f",answer);
        display.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    } else if (operation == "/") {
        answer = String.valueOf(first / second);
        result = String.format("%.0f",answer);
        display.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }

}
```

Variables "first", "second" and "result" are doubles, operation is String.
I did not have this error before, but after a while it started to error those so I added String.valueOf(first + second); , before it was answer = first + second; but adding valueOf fixed that. Now the problem still exists on "result = String.format("%.0f", answer);"

Comment: Please consider string comparision via `.equals()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make `answer` a `double` as well, since you're doing calculations. It's only at display/formatting phase where you should convert to a `String`.

You should put only the calculation part inside the `if` (i.e. `answer = first + second`, with `answer` being a `double`), and afterwards convert it to a String to avoid duplicate code.

Finally use `equals()` to [compare Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), so `operation.equals("+")` and not `==`.

Comment: I changed that operation == "+" to operation.equals("+") and it works the same way as == would. I removed answer and added your result = String.format(...); but it still says, that String cannot be converted to double. Might there be an error with my NetBeans? Because I followed a video guide to make this, it works for him, so did for me but until a moment it popped all those errors.

Comment: Read the linked post, do not use `==` to compare Strings. It doesn't matter if it happens to work by chance this time. Anyway, follow the advice in my answer and it should work nicely.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for that, will remember in future! However, the error exists on result = String.format(...) AND display.setText(result); but I changed this to display.setText(String.valueOf(result)); which I had before and the error disappeared, the only thing that ain't working is the String.format.

Comment: It's still the same basic thing. Do your calculations using `doubles`. Then convert the result to `String` with `String.format()`.

Comment: answer = first + second;
display.setText(String.format("%.0f", answer)); <- This fixed all errors, thank you! =)

Answer (score 1):

With `%.0f` as argument for String formatter, you need to pass a number (a float), but in your snippet `answer` is currently a String.

You can use `%s` in formatter for a String, or (better) pass as second argument the result of the operation as a float instead of a String

To resume :

```
String answer = "1";
System.out.println( String.format("%.0f",answer) ); // Throws an exception


double answer = 1.d;
System.out.println( String.format("%.0f",answer) ); // Prints 1
```

Comment: I changed my answer from string to double right now. The problem still exists.

Comment: @Timppa Please update your post with your current code and error

Comment: double answer;
        second = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        if (operation.equals("+")) {
            answer = first + second;
            result = String.format("%.0f", answer);
            ruutu.setText(String.valueOf(result)); <- This is the most important part of it, rest of the code are basically the same. And error: String cannot be converted to double for the result = String.format(); line

Comment: Where is the declaration of result ? Are you sure is declared as String ?

Comment: Check the correct answer, I fixed it in there by removing one line.

Comment: Yes, sure. So probably i had right : your variable `result` was not declared as a String, and you tried to store a String on it. Impossible for us to confirm, the declaration of result doesn't appear on your post ;)

Answer (score 1):

If result is of double data type

```
double result = first + second;

display.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Comment: Yeah, that fixed one of the problems but String.format is still popping an error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0