# Issue while casting amount to Double

Tags: java

my program is receiving amount value as `string` and then converting it to `Double` using `Double.parseDouble(transAmt)`.

Now we are getting issue when amount passed is `"100.00"` .

Please advise if while casting to double zero precision digits will be lost

Comment: Can you post an isolated example of your problem? It will be easier for people to help.

Comment: and what is the issue?

Comment: There is literally no information to process in this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

With some guessing what the "issue" might be: `double` in Java is an approximation of the mathematical real numbers. As such there is no difference between `100` and `100.00` it is just the same value.

Answer (score 0):

`double` holds no precision, and is an approximation, a sum of (negative) powers of 2. Hence 3.10 might on output be 3.0999999785, an error which enlarges when summing or multiplying.

For holding a precision and being precise - as with financial software - [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is used.

```
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("12.99"); // A precision of 2 digits.
BigDecimal base = new BigDecimal("4.33");
assert base.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(3)).compareTo(amount) == 0;
```

Unfortunately with BigDecimal normal math operators are not available, but in general it is not as unsafe as with double.