# How to Convert String value into Double or Int value in Java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, double

I have a problem. I have `String` with the value `"$615.00"` and I want to convert it to `double` or `int`.
I have tried the following code but there is an error:

```
String one = "$615.00";
String two = "$15.00";
double newone = Double.parseDouble( one );
double newtwo = Double.parseDouble( two );

System.out.println(newone-newtwo);
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$615.00"
```

But I have added the `NumberFormatException` for the method and still got the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert String to double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java)

You are correct... however the $ cannot be used. I recommend you remove the $ before doing the conversion

Comment: Without specifying further, my guess is that `Double#parseDouble(String)` can't handle the `'$'` character. Remove that from the string when you pass it in

Comment: What do you mean by *I have added the NumberFormatException*? you don't catch it anywhere.

Comment: You have them as `String` and you need to remove the currency symbol... Consider using a `BigDecimal`, which takes a `String` in a parameterized constructor and is able to provide a `doubleValue()`.

Comment: There are some answers to your question posted here. Let us know, if they helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, NumberFormatException is happening because you are trying to parseDouble without removing the $ from the number.

In this case, you can use [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) to get everything after the first char:

```
String one = "$615.00";
String two = "$15.00";

double newone = Double.parseDouble( one.substring(1) );
double newtwo = Double.parseDouble( two.substring(1) );

System.out.println(newone-newtwo);
```

Results in 600.00

Comment: And what if there will be spaces, digits or other symbols (more than one and on another positions)? For me this is very hardcoded solution

Comment: Then you'd need a more complex solution, but for any prefixes or sufixes you need to remove, this works

Comment: If the dollar symbol will be a suffix, or there will be 2 options for its position, you will need to change the code and add additional checkings. In other words excess code. This is a major drawback of the solution. You need to write the code in a way, that will provide robust solution with possible changing input data formats

Comment: I agree, your answer with the regular expression is more complete, but I though a simpler solution could help better in this case, since regular expressions are kinda tricky

Comment: Well, assuming the author of question is a beginner, it might be easier and more convenient for him to use your solution. So you do have a point and your answer makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a currency designator.  It is not part of a numeric value.

If you have a currency value, you should use a [currency format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance%28%29) to read it:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
double newone = format.parse(one).doubleValue();
double newtwo = format.parse(two).doubleValue();
```

If you are not running on a computer configured for the US, you may need to pass a Locale, to force the currency instance to use US dollars:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
double newone = format.parse(one).doubleValue();
double newtwo = format.parse(two).doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to remove symbols like "$" (in other words, all symbols but digits and dot)

```
String one = "$615.03";
String oneValue = one.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
System.out.println(oneValue); // Output is 615.03, which is correctly parsed by parseDobule()
```

Comment: Using a regular expression is overkill.  Regular expressions are heavyweight, and hard to read and debug.  They should not be used unless they are truly needed.

Comment: @VGR I don't think that debugging and reading `if-else` statements is easier than reading the single line with pattern. Also, just a single possibility of input data becoming "615.00$" makes it easier to use regex. I would like to know about a better solution for preprocessing strings, since I got voted down