# Java cast a string as a double

Tags: java

Im creating a basic GUI that takes the amount entered by a user and subtracts it with a pre existing amount. However it will not let me to run the one below as I get an error of String cannot be converted to double.  Using the parseInt method won't work here as im using the getText Method.

```
String message = txtaMessage.getText();
    String transaction1 = txtfAmountTransfer.getText();
    String reciever = txtfTransferTo.getText();
    
    lblOutputTransferInfo.setText("Your Amount of "+transaction1+" has been sent to "+reciever+" .");
    lblOutputTransferMsg.setText("With a Message: "+ message);

   double balance = 5123.84;
   
   String newBalance = balance - transaction1;//this will not work but the concept I need 
   
   lblSavingsBalance.setText(newBalance);
```

Comment: You need to parse the string `transaction1` as a double before you attempt to use it for calculation, then you need to convert it back to a string. For example, `String newBalance = balance - Double.parseDouble(transaction1) + "";` See here [Javadoc - Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert String to double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because here transcation1 is a string and whereas balance is double. In java, we don't have a method to subtract string from double. So, First, you need to convert `transaction1` into double. I suggest you to
`Double newBalance = balance - Double.parseDouble(transcation1);`
then `lblSavingsBalance.setText(newBalance.toString());` to convert `newBalance` double value to string

Hope it works fine...

Comment: You can also do it in one line using `String newBalance = balance - Double.parseDouble(transaction1) + "";` note the `+""` at the end which converts the doubles back to string.

Answer (score 0):

**If getText returns String below code will work.**

```
        String message = txtaMessage.getText();
    String transaction1 = txtfAmountTransfer.getText();

    String reciever = txtfTransferTo.getText();


    lblOutputTransferInfo.setText("Your Amount of "+transaction1+" has been sent to "+reciever+" .");

    lblOutputTransferMsg.setText("With a Message: "+ message);

    double balance = 5123.84;

    balance = balance - Double.parseDouble(transaction1);//this will not work but the concept I need

    lblSavingsBalance.setText(String.valueOf(balance));
```

**If you are using android**,

(Assuming txtaMessage, transaction1, reciever are either TextView objects or EditText objects)

```
txtaMessage.getText(); //This won't return a String. This will return a CharSequence.
```

You have to convert it to string. So the correct method is,

```
String message = txtaMessage.getText().toString();
```

Do this for all EditTexts and TextViews.

Then transaction1 shoud be converted as Double

```
Double.parseDouble(transaction1);
```

After that you can substract transtraction1 from balance and assign it to the original balance.

```
balance = balance - Double.parseDouble(transaction1)
```

**The full version of android code is below.**

```
        String message = txtaMessage.getText().toString();
    String transaction1 = txtfAmountTransfer.getText().toString();

    String reciever = txtfTransferTo.getText().toString();


    lblOutputTransferInfo.setText("Your Amount of "+transaction1+" has been sent to "+reciever+" .");

    lblOutputTransferMsg.setText("With a Message: "+ message);

    double balance = 5123.84;
    
    balance = (balance - Double.parseDouble(transaction1));//this will not work but the concept I need
        lblSavingsBalance.setText(String.valueOf(balance));
```

If the **transaction1** value is not a number, An Exception will occur. So wrapping it with try/ catch is a good idea.

```
            try {
        balance = (balance - Double.parseDouble(transaction1));//this will not work but the concept I need
        lblSavingsBalance.setText(String.valueOf(balance));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //Send error message like showing a toast
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Your first method works however every time I enter another amount it doesn't add up by the actual amount.  It goes up by the difference.  If transaction1 was 100 my new balance does show 5023.  However when I enter a new transaction of 200 it shows 4923 which is $200 from the old balance and not the new balance.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about your text inputs. Specially,  txtaMessage, transaction1, reciever. I will update my answer with best guesses, But is's good to know from you.

Comment: I've updated my code.

Comment: txtaMessage and receiver don't really have much to do with what I want I basically need the amount to subtract from the new balance each time instead of going back to my first balance.  If my double balance is set to 5123.84 and I make a transaction of 100.  It'll show 5023.84 which is good.  But then when I make another amount transaction it starts back to the balance of 5123.84 instead of 5023.84.

Comment: As I told before, I've changed code. Now check the new code. These are the changed lines. Instead of declaring a new variable for new balance, we can update the old balace. So the problem is solved.

    balance = balance - Double.parseDouble(transaction1);//this will not work but the concept I need

    lblSavingsBalance.setText(String.valueOf(balance));